# Can AI accurately predict specific details of criminal activity, such as when, where, and who?

Tags: prediction

Combating illegal activities is a complex challenge for societies around the world. The use of advanced technologies, such as artificial intelligence (AI) and big data, has the potential to assist in this endeavor, depending on comprehensive databases and robust processing capabilities.

I am interested in understanding the current state and potential of AI systems to accurately predict the specific details of criminal activity. Specifically:

1. **Temporal and Spatial Accuracy**: Can AI systems predict the precise date, time, and location of criminal incidents, encompassing latitude, longitude, and street addresses?
2. **Perpetrator Profiling**: Is there existing AI capable of providing insights into potential perpetrators, including details such as educational background, economic conditions, and geographic origin?

I welcome insights into the existing technologies, theoretical possibilities, and ethical implications surrounding the intersection of AI and crime prediction.

I value diverse perspectives on the current state of AI in this area and potential future advances.

Comment: oh you mean predicting the future? we cannot reliably not even forecast weather, let alone the future

Comment: Are you looking for prediction of going back to time or predict future possible crime?

Comment: I am interested in predicting future possible crimes, perhaps there are patterns of previous occurrence of crimes that can be analyzed and use this data for predicting future crimes. I know that predicting future crimes is a real-world challenge, probably very difficult to tackle using data and algorithms. But is there a way or a possibility to do it? It might be useful if we can analyze patterns to be more accurate and detailed for future prediction. I would appreciate insights and perspectives on the current state of research and applications in this area.

Comment: Police departments (in USA) really have trialed map based, machine-assisted statistics and used them to assign patrols. Ignoring the more far-fetched ideas like Minority Report, this is a real thing and there are real social and moral concerns as well as technical